# Does Javascript Array.map() return a different instance object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I use `Array.map()` to replace each null element with an instance of object like this.

```
let arr = new Array(10).fill(null).map(() => new LinkedList());
```

Does this replace each element with the same referenced `LinkedList()` instance or different reference?

Comment: Well, you can easily find out, if you add an element to `arr[0]` and check whether it is also contained in all others

Comment: It doesn't *replace* anything. You are looping over an array of 10 elements and creating another array with `new LinkedList()` objects. It's like `for(let i =0; i < 10; i++) arr.push(new LinkedList())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a map function will pay attention to the existing value in the array it is being used to process so it has to be called for each item in the array and will generate a new value *for each item*.

```js
const double = value => 2 * value;
const doubled = [1, 2, 3].map(double);
console.log(doubled);
```

It *isn't* called once and the value used for every position.

You'll get a new instance for each position because the function will be called each time.

You can trivially test this with a comparison:

```js
function LinkedList() {};
let arr = new Array(10).fill(null).map(() => new LinkedList());
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0] === arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get 10 different instance of `new LinkedList()`.
You could verify that by checking `console.log(arr[0] === arr[1])`.

Answer (score -1):

It should be different References.